# How to validate only part of the model in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I have a large model (large I mean model class contains a lot of fields/properties and each has at least one validation attribute (such as `Required`, `MaxLength`, `MinLength` etc)). Instead of creating one view with a lot of inputs for user to fill model with data I want to create several views where user will fill part of model fields and go to the next step (some kind of *"wizard"*). While redirecting between steps I store not fullfilled model object in `Session`. Something like below:

Model:

```
public class ModelClass
{
    [MaxLength(100)] ...
    public string Prop1{get;set;}
    [MaxLength(100)] ...
    public string Prop2{get;set;}
    ...
    [Required][MaxLength(100)] ...
    public string Prop20{get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step1(ModelClass postedModel)
{    
    // user posts only for example Prop1 and Prop2
    // so while submit I have completly emty model object
    // but with filled Prop1 and Prop2
    // I pass those two values to Session["model"]
    var originalModel = Session["model"] as ModelClass ?? new ModelClass();
    originalModel.Prop1 = postedModel.Prop1;
    originalModel.Prop2 = postedModel.Prop2;
    Session["model"] = originalModel;

    // and return next step view
    return View("Step2");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step2(ModelClass postedModel)
{
    // Analogically the same
    // I have posted only Prop3 and Prop4

    var originalModel = Session["model"] as ModelClass;
    if (originalModel!=null)
    {
        originalModel.Prop3 = postedModel.Prop3;
        originalModel.Prop4 = postedModel.Prop4;
        Session["model"] = originalModel;

        // return next step view
        return View("Step3");
    }
    return View("SomeErrorViewIfSessionBrokesSomeHow")
}
```

`Step1` view has inputs only for `Prop1` and `Prop2`, Step2 view contains inputs for `Prop3` and `Prop4` etc.

**BUT HERE IS THE THING**

When user is on, for example, step 1, and fills Prop1 with value more than 100 characters length client side validation works fine. But, of course , I have to validate this value and on the server side in controller. If I had full model I'd just do the following:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid) return View("the same view with the same model object");
```

so user has to fill the form again and correct.
**BUT** on step 1 user has filled only 2 properties of 20, and I need to validate them. I can't use `ModelState.IsValid` because model state will be invalid. As You can see `Prop20` is marked with `[Required]` attribute, when user submits `Prop1` and `Prop2`, `Prop20` is null and that's why `ModelState` is invalid. Of course I could allow user to go to step2, fill all of the steps and validate model state only on the last step but I don't want to allow user to go to step 2 if he filled step 1 incorrect. And I want this validation in controller. *So the question is:*
**How can I validate only part of the model? How can I verify that only some of the model properties match their validation attributes?**

Comment: You could create a different view model for each step which could be a seperate view.  Like ProductStep1ViewModel and ProductStep1View, but I would name them better than that.

Comment: @NickBray, ModelClass is view model class, mapped from original model, so if I create ModelClass as composition of other particular step classes I will have to add about 40 mapping rules for mapper to map those model classes, and it will be a bunch of code. I've already thought about that, but thanks for advice.

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavsky You could use something like [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) instead to avoid having to set up mapping rules explicitly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One possible solution:

1. Use ModelState.IsValidField(string key);

   ```
   if (ModelState.IsValidField("Name") && ModelState.IsValidField("Address"))
   { ... }
   ```

Then at the end when everything is done use:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid) { .. }
```

Comment: If you fill in a non excisting string it wil always return, make sure that you type it correctly.

Answer (score 11):

I think the most elegant way is to do it like that:

```
List<string> PropertyNames = new List<string>()
{
    "Prop1",
    "Prop2"
};

if (PropertyNames.Any(p => !ModelState.IsValidField(p)))
{
    // Error
}
else
{
    // Everything is okay
}
```

or:

```
List<string> PropertyNames = new List<string>()
{
    "Prop1",
    "Prop2"
};

if (PropertyNames.All(p => ModelState.IsValidField(p)))
{
    // Everything is okay
}
else
{
    // Error
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In MVC Core, this will be the equivalent of:

```
if (ModelState.GetFieldValidationState("Name") == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Valid)
{
    // do something
}
```

However, I would recommend simply **creating a separate view model** in this instance.

Your partial view model could be inherited by your larger view model so you won't have to repeat yourself in code (DRY principal).

It's better to avoid hard-coding the property names!

Comment: It works in my Core 2.1 API project - since MVC and Web API now share the same ControllerBase class.  You can see that `ModelState` live in ControllerBase in Core 2 as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.modelstate?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: There are plenty of examples of using ModelState validation in .NET Core Web API.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api Just play with it until you get it

Comment: I have raised my own question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755073/how-to-validate-only-a-part-of-model-state-in-asp-net-core-2-web-api) .. See if you and me are on same page..  i have already seen the link you have suggested..

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the existing answers for this. Rather than hardcoding the property names I would use an attribute to be added along with the rest of your validation attributes along the lines of:

```
public class ValidationStageAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int StageNumber { get; private set; }
    public ValidationStageAttribute(int stageNumber)
    {
        StageNumber = stageNumber;
    }
}
```

Now that we can get the property names without knowledge of the model itself the partial validation can be pulled into a method (if you use it a lot, your base controller would be a good spot).

```
protected bool ValidateStage(object viewModel, int stageToValidate)
{
    var propertiesForStage = viewModel.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(prop => prop.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<ValidationStageAttribute>().Any(attr => attr.StageNumber == stageToValidate))
        .Select(prop => prop.Name);

    return propertiesForStage.All(p => ModelState.IsValidField(p));
}
```

Now all you'd need to do in your post action would be to call `ValidateStage(viewModel, 1)`