# How to validate only a part of Model State in asp.net core 2 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0

We are using a Usermaster DTO in 2 different projects.

```
public class UserMaster : BaseProperties
{      

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }        
}
```

Now we are using this DTO in 2 different projects. 

**Project 1** is Admin in asp.net MVC 5.0, There we can use ModelState.IsValidField to validate only a part of this whole Model. 
  **Project 2** is a Web Api build in asp.net core 2. There i could not find any solution which can only validate Email and Password for login purpose.. 
***Basically i am facing issue in asp.net core 2 web api where i could not specify the exact data member that could be only validate. I have to pass anything on other [Required] fields to validate request. likewise ModelState.IsValidField*** 
 Any solutions??

Comment: *Don't* use the same DTO in both projects. If you have different validation requirements it's a *very* strong indicator that you need different DTOs. Besides, the *Model* is made to serve the *View*. If it has *anything* that prevents it from doing that, it shouldn't be used as a model for *that* view.

Comment: Seems to me that you want to split the this into two classes as the intented purpose differs

Comment: Create a new model appropriate for the view and map existing DTOs to it using eg AutoMapper.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, We are using mongoDb as backend which are strongly binded with DTOs. We choose this way to decrease the maintenance work.. Else we need to update in both the project for every bit of change

Comment: @Arjun and that's why you *SHOULDN'T* use that DTO. It's your *service layer DTO*, not your ViewModel. It won't fit the view's needs 99.99999% of the time. Map it to appropriate ViewModel models. What are you going to do when you need to add a password strenght indicator?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, ok i got that idea.. But why i am not able to get something like asp.net MVC have? like ModelState.IsValidField works very well in that project

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different validation requirements, then you should have two different view models/DTOs. The whole entire point of a view model/DTO is handle particular usage scenario. Here, you have two different sets of request data, so your issue is entirely down to trying to use the same class to satisfy both, when the two are not the same.

If you want to reduce code duplication, simply continue using inheritance:

```
public class UserLogin : BaseProperties
{
    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class UserMaster : UserLogin
{      

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Yea.. i have considered this my last option.. Actually i was carried away with ModelState.IsValidField so thought there will be also some sol in core.. Along with that i was thinking, this is only just one instance.. What if there are many scenarios like this in cuming project modules.. I might keep on depending on inheritance only :(

Comment: You'll have to see how your classes should best be designed. Perhaps inheritance is not the right approach. Still, a DTO class is inherently a special purpose class, so it should be used for that purpose and that's it. It can be reused if you're doing the same type of things in multiple places, but it is a mistake to try to make one class or even one hierarchy of classes handle every possible scenario. Besides, using a specific class for a specific API endpoint serves as documentation. You know exactly what that endpoint needs.

Answer (score 0):

in your DTO implement IValidatableObject

```
public class UserMaster : BaseProperties, IValidatableObject
{      

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonRequired]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }      

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
    //you custom validation here...
    }  
}
```

So if you can detect the context it is being used in then you are on your way...

Comment: Won't it will be applicable to both the projects?

Comment: `public class NewUserMaster : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Required]
        public string EmailId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailId))
                yield return new ValidationResult("Email is required");
        }
    }`

Comment: see the above sample class (in better text editor) , i have post only Email value but it also raises "Password is required" error. So how can i skip validating password field??